# Flutter. Ограничить ввод в TextFormField диапазоном чисел

Tags: flutter, dart

Необходимо ограничить ввод TextFormField диапазоном чисел. Например, от 7 до 112. Что для этого нужно использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать inputFormatters, чтобы достичь желаемого результата. Но придется немного подумать все же.

```
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    TextInputFormatter.withFunction(
      (oldValue, newValue) {
        String _value = newValue.text;
        int num = _value.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), '').toInt();
        if (_value.length > 3)
          return TextEditingValue(
            text: oldValue.text,
            selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
              offset: oldValue.selection.end,
            ),
          );

        if (num < 7 &&) num = 7;
        if (num > 112) num = 112;
        return TextEditingValue(
          text: '$num',
          selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
            offset: num.length,
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

Я накидал самый примитивный пример, надеюсь, вы справитесь.)